# Unable to access actuator endpoints when deployed on Google App Engine 11

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, maven-3, java-11, spring-boot-actuator

I have an inherited spring boot application that was happily living on GAE 8 standard running on jetty. We are in the process of upgrading it to GAE 11 standard.

Based the [Differences between Java 8 and Java 11/17](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/java-differences) we determined that we would try to Migrating to Java 11/17 with bundled services and followed the instructions to [Access bundled services using the App Engine APIs JAR.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/services/access).

The ***appengine-web.xml*** and ***pom.xml*** were updated as specified above, although we do not have a ***web.xml***, we needed `<app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>` to prevent some errors on start up because we previously used `<sessions-enabled>` to secure actuator endpoints. *We do not use* an ***app.yaml*** yet.

There are some release scripts in the code that suggest I should be able to access the actuator endpoints for smoke testing our DEV project to compare against our production endpoints prior to release, for instance `/_ah/health`, so that is where I am starting to validate my upgrade. So far...

- I can access `/_ah/health` in our current version in production  (GAE
  8).
- I can access `/_ah/health` in our current version in development
  (GAE 8).
- I can access `/_ah/health` locally on `http:8080` after
  `clean package appengine:run`  (GAE 11, branch), Google App Engine
  Maven plugin (deploy)
- I **cannot access** `/_ah/health` and get ***404 Error: Not Found*** when deployed to out dev (GAE 11, branch)

I've turned up the logs. I can see that is falls through several security filters but I still get a 404:

1. WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
2. SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
3. HeaderWriterFilter
4. CorsFilter
5. LogoutFilter
6. BasicAuthenticationFilter
7. RequestCacheAwareFilter
8. SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
9. AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
10. SessionManagementFilter
11. ExceptionTranslationFilter

***So I am thinking this is related to the Security Configuration.***

The intention is to allow the /health and /health/** for all but secure all other actuator endpoints with basic authentication (configured user/pass) in ***application.yml***

Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I think are some valid config files. notes and logs...

- All of the necessary work to upgrade the underlying spring boot application from java 8 to 11 (as suggested by many articles/checklists on the web) was completed many months ago and now we are compiling to java 11 and upgrading our GAE deployment.

**appengine-web.xml updated for java 11**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <service>my-api</service>
  <runtime>java11</runtime>
  <instance-class>F4</instance-class>
  <app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>
  <!-- To allow securing actuator endpoints with a login -->
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
  <automatic-scaling>
  <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
  </automatic-scaling>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**application.yml**

```
# ...
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      # GAE Standard Runtime looks for health checks under /_ah - not sure if valid any more
      base-path: /_ah
      exposure:
        include: env,health
  health:
    probes:
    # This enables base-path/health/liveness and base-path/health/readiness
      enabled: true
    # This health check will fail on GAE Standard Runtime
    diskspace:
      enabled: false
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: foo
      password: bar
      roles: ADMIN
# ...
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").anonymous()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
  // ...
}
```

**ServletInitializer.java**

```
Public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using `Cloud SDK v395.0.0`? Could you try deploying your application using an older version of Cloud SDK by changing your App Engine maven plugin in your `pom.xml`? Also as per checking, a similar issue has been reported already in [Google Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/240455023)

Comment: @CatherineO, good catch! 

We are using `com.google.cloud.tools.appengine-maven-plugin` version `2.4.0`. We did not specify `<cloudSdkVersion>` in the plugins configuration, thus we were using (`Cloud SDK v395.0.0`). The last known good version used in a successful deployment for this services was  `Cloud SDK v371.0.0`  using this version I was again able to access my endpoints. 

your tracker link did not work for me but I found  [App Engine Standard Java 8: 404 Not Found](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240455023) - which I think is the issue referenced.

Comment: Thats good to hear @jtsampson. I've posted the workaround as an answer. You can accept the answer so the question will be marked as solved. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments section, using an older working version of Cloud SDK (in this case `v371.0.0`) resulted in being able to successfully access the endpoints again.

Additionally, the issue has already been reported in the issue tracker: [App Engine Standard Java 8: 404 Not Found](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/240455023)

Comment: Catherine O, please update your links above and use the public tracker urls. Your links look like partner links and require authentication.